# Easy way to split column into two in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` in Pandas that looks like this:

```py
transactions_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-08-01', '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01'], 'Amount': [150, -25, 200]})
transactions_df.head()
```

```
Date        Amount
2019-08-01  150
2019-09-01  -25
2019-10-01  200
```

I want to split the amount column into `Invoiced` and `Reimbursed`, if the value is positive or negative, respectively.

I am currently doing it like this:

```py
def split_trans_amount(row):
    invoiced = row['Amount'] if row['Amount'] > 0 else 0
    reimbursed = row['Amount'] if row['Amount'] < 0 else 0

    return pd.Series([invoiced, reimbursed], index=['Invoiced', 'Reimbursed'])

transactions_in_out_df = transactions_df.apply(lambda x: split_trans_amount(x), axis=1)
transactions_split_df = pd.concat([transactions_df, transactions_in_out_df], axis=1)
transactions_split_df.head()
```

It gives me what I need:

```
Date        Amount      Invoiced    Reimbursed
2019-08-01  150         150         0
2019-09-01  -25         0           -25
2019-10-01  200         200         0
```

But, isn't there an easier way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.clip(..)` here:

```
transactions_df['Invoiced'] = transactions_df['Amount'].values.clip(min=0)
transactions_df['Reimbursed'] = transactions_df['Amount'].values.clip(max=0)
```

This gives us:

```
>>> transactions_df
         Date  Amount  Invoiced  Reimbursed
0  2019-08-01     150       150           0
1  2019-09-01     -25         0         -25
2  2019-10-01     200       200           0
```

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I was looking for. I will accept the answer when I get past the 10 minute threshold they enforce.

Answer (score 1):

```
transactions_df['Invoiced'] = transactions_df['Amount'].multiply(transactions_df['Amount']>0)
transactions_df['Reimbursed'] = transactions_df['Amount'].multiply(transactions_df['Amount']<0)
```

also works

```
         Date  Amount  Invoiced  Reimbursed
0  2019-08-01     150       150           0
1  2019-09-01     -25         0         -25
2  2019-10-01     200       200           0
```